# How to specify access token in Blogger Google API to insert a post?

Tags: java, google-api, blogger

I am exploring Google Blogger's API. I want to insert a post from a Java standalone application. I have managed to generate an authentication code and an access token.

I am trying to follow the code example available [here](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert), but it does not specify how to set the access token. Can anyone clarify this? Do you have an operational code example to share?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your access token in the headers of your HTTP request.

```
Authorization:  Bearer yourAccessTokenHere
```

Comment: Agreed, but I was hoping I could use the code example provided by Google to dodge boiler plate code...

Comment: A good solution to avoid Boiler plate code would be to use the java lib that Google provides. It manages those kind of headers, but also refreshing the tokens automatically, etc... You can find the one for blogger here : http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Blogger_API

Comment: That's precisely what I did (lol), but when I went into details, the pieces of the puzzle don't fit well or at all. Some links are broken...But I am digging into it...

Comment: yeah the samples are not always very good. But usually, they have a pattern : you build `GoogleCredential` with the `GoogleCredential.Builder`, you build your service with his builder, specifying your Creds in the builder"constructor